# How can I get a value from a JSON file from python function

Tags: python, json, discord.py

Okay so here's how I setup the JSON file:

```py
async def openinf():
    with open("infractions.json", "r") as f:
        users = json.load(f)
    return users

async def createinfraction(user, type, mod, date, caseid):
        users = await openinf()

        users[str(user.id)] = {}
        users[str(user.id)]["type"] = type
        users[str(user.id)]["mod"] = mod.id
        users[str(user.id)]["date"] = date
        users[str(user.id)]["caseid"] = caseid


        with open("infractions.json", "w") as f:
            json.dump(users, f)
            print("done function")
        return True
```

This would print this in a json file:  `{"581457749724889102": {"type": "Warning", "mod": 581457749724889102, "date": "04/12/2021 18:52:28", "caseid": "f59427df-552a-11ec-8dfd-e03f49c55de5"}}`

Now, I tried doing this:

```py
try:

            users = await openinf()

            type = users[str(member.id)]["type"]
            modid = users[str(member.id)]["mod"]
            date = users[str(member.id)]["date"]
            caseid = users[str(member.id)]["caseid"]

            embed = discord.Embed(title = f"Infractions for {member}", colour = 0x0f9492)
            i = 1
            mod = await client.fetch_user(modid)
            for user in users:
                if user == member.id:
                    print("yes")
                    i += 1
                    embed.add_field(name= f"Infraction #{i}",  value = f"**{type}** \nCase ID: {caseid}\nModerator: {mod}\nDate:{date}\n", inline = False )
```

But this doesn't help me, it doesn't return any error (i've put an except that would print the error after). I assume that I didn't get the id object correctly.

Comment: Question isn't clear to me. Do you want to return a value from the json file (infractions.json) using a function?

Comment: yes, basically i need the ID (581457749724889102 in the example i gave)

Comment: Have you tried `print`ing `users`? Wrapping everything in a blanket `try` `except` is not a good way to debug. Let the error happen if it does and include the traceback in your question.

Comment: Perhaps you’ve omitted some code, but there’s no reason for either of these functions to be asynchronous. They don’t await anything and as such as blocking functions.

Answer (score 0):

if `user == member.id:` is wrong as the dict key `user` is not a number, its a string.

you need to type cast it to an integer to do the compare

```
if int(user) == member.id:
    ...
```

or

```
if user == str(member.id):
    ...
```

does the trick.

As you already type cast the member.id several times, move that to its own variable and use that through out the code.

```
member_id = str(member.id)
```